# Unable to get correct center for CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift3, cashapelayer

Can someone please point out what am i doing incorrectly? I need to adapt to all iphone screens in portrait. is this a good approach?

```
var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()

    let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: vu_SubmissionViewWithImageInCenter.bounds.width / 2, y: imgVu_Submission.bounds.width / 2)
    let circleRadius : CGFloat = vu_SubmissionViewWithImageInCenter.bounds.width / 2 * 0.94

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    )

    progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
    progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath
    progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.fuschia.cgColor
    progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressCircle.lineWidth = 3.5
    progressCircle.strokeStart = 0
    progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0
    vu_SubmissionViewWithImageInCenter.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)


    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1.0
    animation.duration = 5.0
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: "ani")
    animation.delegate = self
```

[image: IB to show constraints how can i adapt the drawing to these constraints to make it draw perfectly on all portraits?]
[5s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwkV2.png)
[image: 7]

Comment: What method contains the code in your question?

Comment: @robmayoff viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: Is `vu_SubmissionViewWithImageInCenter` a subview of the view controller's view?

Comment: yes. in IB ive checked it twice

Comment: Have you considered what the method name `viewWillLayoutSubviews` means, as compared to the method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: still the same i tried it last night thinking the bezier path is drawing on the pre-run frame

Answer (score -1):

Your radius calculation is wrong. Have a distance calculation from arc centre to the imageview edges and use that as your radius.

Comment: the problem isnt the radius, its the drawing center